# Creating a numbered menu list from a database fetch - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am trying to fetch content from several rows in a database and list and number them for a menu. I figured out how to list the items using join as such:

```
for i in (row):
    print("".join(i))
```

Which returns:

```
 Test
 Test2
 Test3
 Test4
```

What I need returned is:

```
 1.Test
 2.Test2
 3.Test3
 4.Test4
```

I currently use a list for the menu with the following:

```
for i, m in enumerate(menu, start=1):
    print("{} - {}".format(i, m)
```

However I cannot get this format to work with the database fetch and join. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer without seeing a bit more code; however, to add numbers to the code you posted above just do:

```
for k, i in enumerate(row):
    print(str(k+1) + "." + "".join(i))
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I had a menu list and sub menu lists and my code was just getting too crowded with lists so I wanted to free up space by just pulling the menu items straight from the rows in the db to make the code more neat.  I am new to programming, I am not sure if that is the best way to make menus, but the code sure looks better without tons of lists. Thank you. :)

Comment: if this is the solution you are looking for, please accept it as the solution; more info here on how to do that  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work